# Attaching an email as an attachment to another email

Tags: c#

I would like to know how to attach an email as an attachment to another email in C#.
Details:

1. I am writing a plugin for outlook
2. I am getting the error on this line : Attachment attach = new Attachment(mailItem, new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html; charset=us-ascii"));
3. Error message is : Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment'
4. Sample code below

   ```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
   {
       Explorer explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
       Selection selection = explorer.Selection;

       if (selection.Count > 0)   // Check that selection is not empty.
       {
           object selectedItem = selection[1];   // Index is one-based.
           MailItem mailItem = selectedItem as MailItem;


           if (mailItem != null)    // Check that selected item is a message.
           {
               System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
               message.To.Add("blah@blah.com");
               message.Subject = "blah";
               message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("test@test.com");
               message.Body = "This is the message body";

                Attachment attach = new Attachment(mailItem, new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html; charset=us-ascii"));
                message.Attachments.Add(attach);
               System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smlsmtp");
               smtp.Send(message);

           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: If you are integrating with Outlook, reading MailItems from it, why send mail using SMTP? Why not create and send in Outlook?

Comment: No reason at all. This is the first time I've ever tried to do anything with Outlook. If there is an easier way to use outlook to send the mails then I guess that would be better. I will go have a look from now. If you know of any resources that could help please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a bit more reading/searching, I was able to find something that works. Probably the most difficult part is the first line.

```
                try
                {
                    Outlook.MailItem tosend = (Outlook.MailItem)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                    tosend.Attachments.Add(mailItem);
                    tosend.To = "blah@blah.com";
                    tosend.Subject = "test";
                    tosend.Body = "blah";
                    tosend.Save();
                    tosend.Send();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught: ", ex);
                }
```

Thanks to @Kris Vandermotten for pointing me in the right direction